# Laravel 5.2 Eloquent Order Query by Eagerly Loaded Data

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Is it possible to order the results of an Eloquent query by the eagerly loaded data.  To be clear I get the right data, it is paginated properly, and works in every way except it isn't ordered the way I need it to be.  In this case I'd like to sort users by profile.firstname.

Something like this:

```
$results = User::where('id', '!=', $user->id)
               ->whereNotIn('id', $ids)
               ->with([
                   'profile' => function ($query) {
                       $query->addSelect(['id', 'first_name', 'last_name']);
                   },
               ])
               ->orderBy('profile.first_name', 'desc')
               ->paginate();
```

The data is used in an Ionic application and is used for an infinite scroll so I need to have the data in the format below ordered by first_name prior to being received on the client, but the above example doesn't work.

**DATA needed for Ionic View**

```
user: {
  id: '1',
  username: 'aUsername'
  email: 'anEmail'
  profile: {
    id: '2',
    user_id: '1',
    first_name: 'aFirstName',
    last_name: 'aLastName',
    phone_number: '999-999-9999'
  }
}
...
```

**Solution (with flattened result set)**

```
$results = User::join('user_profiles', 'users.id', '=', 'user_profiles.user_id')
               ->select('users.id', 'users.username', 'user_profiles.first_name', 'user_profiles.last_name')
               ->where('users.id', '!=', $user->id)
               ->whereNotIn('id', $existingContactIds)
               ->where('users.username', 'like', $request->input('username') . '%')
               ->orderBy('user_profiles.first_name')
               ->paginate();
```

**Solution (with proper result format)**

```
    $results = User::where('users.id', '!=', $user->id)
                   ->whereNotIn('users.id', $existingContactIds)
                   ->where('users.username', 'like', $request->input('username') . '%')
                   ->with([
                       'profile' => function ($query) use ($columns) {
                           $query->addSelect('user_profiles.first_name', 'user_profiles.last_name');
                       },
                   ])
                   ->select('users.id', 'users.username')
                   ->join('user_profiles', 'users.id', '=', 'user_profiles.user_id')
                   ->orderBy('user_profiles.first_name')
                   ->paginate();
```

Comment: Could you share corresponding template code?

Comment: To support pagination, you have to handle specific parameters in your query builder (like limit and offset).

Comment: Hi, I'm not having any issues with pagination just how the result is ordered

Comment: are you receiving any error? in that case share, pls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ordering by another table, you need to perform a join.

Chain in a join for your profile table

```
-> join('profiles', 'profiles.id', '=', 'users.profile_id')
```

You'll then be able to orderBy first_name (though not profile.first_name).

It isn't possible to orderBy eager loaded tables. If you look at the SQL Laravel produces, you'll see that it firsts gets all the results from the users tables then passes the IDs of just the results (so a subset of all results if you're using pagination) to the profiles table to get relevant data.

You could sometimes avoid the join by using the Collection method sortBy on the results, but this won't work when coupled with pagination as sortBy only works on the results, so will be ordering a subset of data only (but sortBy does support the dot notation you've tried using for your orderBy).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the description and answer that definitely solved the issue of ordering, but introduced an issue regarding the format of the JSON data returned to the client.  I noticed the query builder doesn't return a collection so I can't run a filter on the data prior to calling paginate().  How would you get the now flattened object back to a format like the example above?  I thought I'd just grab the data, collect, filter, and replace the pagination data, but `$results['data']` doesn't provide the data, and neither does `$results->data`.

Comment: @mtpultz It should always return a Collection. Could you paste the full query you're now using.

Comment: Hi, I posted the solution in the question.  Seems to return an array similar to Laravel's query builder.

Comment: Hi, I figured by your answer that this should work then I noticed I wasn't eager loading anymore in my answer.  I posted a second solution using eager loading that works.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Im seeing your code and I think it should be `->orderBy('profile->first_name', 'desc')`   or  try this other way `->orderBy('first_name', 'desc')`

Answer (score 0):

Try like this
`$results = User::where('id', '!=', $user->id)
               ->whereNotIn('id', $ids)
               ->with([
                   'profile' => function ($query) {
                       $query->addSelect(['id', 'first_name', 'last_name']);
                       $query->orderBy('first_name','DESC');
                   },
               ])
               ->paginate();`